# Links in markdown cause code validation failure

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks, validation

Below you'll find some markdown that I tried to post as the [answer for a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515428/running-jasmine-unit-testing-with-angular-2-from-cdn-running-systemjs/43542575#43542575).

- When I tried to click submit I get the validation error which is also below regarding a malformed code block
- When I removed the the links `[few issues][zonejs-project-issues]` and `[zone.js project][zonejs-project]` then I was able to submit the answer.
- If I try and edit the answer and add the links back in, then I fail validation again

**What is wrong with the markdown below that causes the validation failure?** Interestingly the paragraph can be posted successfully independent of the rest of the content i.e. create a new post with just the paragraph and the links.

## Failing Markdown

```
There seems to be two parts to this question, so i'll call them out and answer them individually.

# Can we run jasmine unit testing with angular2 from CDN running systemjs?

**Yes. I've created a [plunker][plunker] that seems to do what you wanted to do.**

At the time of this answer, the systemjs.config.js in this plunk has been pretty hacked to help illustrate the changes, but I've copied the important parts below in case I clean it up in the future. The main changes that I needed to make to go from an older RC to the "latest" angular2 release version (2.4 at the time of writing) was to resolve the testing dependencies from the CDN for:


- @angular/core/testing
- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing
- @angular/platform-browser/testing
- @angular/compiler/testing


And here's the appropriate fragment

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var map = {
        ...
        "@angular/core/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.4.0/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js",
        "@angular/platform-browser/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.4.0/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js",
        "@angular/compiler/testing": "https://npmcdn.com/@angular/compiler@2.4.0/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js",
       ...
    };


**Note:** I am mapping the /testing dependencies to the umd format packages in the /bundles location. It looks like you're trying to map to the index.js inside @angular/core/testing/index which from what I can tell isn't the dependency that you're looking for, we want umd in this case.

# Is there any reason why the latest version cannot run unit testing with Angular 2 via a CDN url?

Regarding the second part of your question, It seems you may be referencing the latest zone.js dependency as opposed to angular2.

**No, there isn't a reason I can see.** With the right configuration it works perfectly well with the version I tested:

- 0.6.21
- 0.6.23
- 0.6.25 which was the latest 0.6.x (at the time of writing)

I did find that there were a lot of changes and a [few issues][zonejs-project-issues] were raised in the [zone.js project][zonejs-project] around this time, though many seem to be resolved by the versions we're talking about. the right configuration and order were important in my test running page where I have the fragment.

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/async-test.js?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/fake-async-test.js?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/sync-test.js?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/proxy.js?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.25/dist/jasmine-patch.js?main=browser"></script>


I hope this is helpful to you 7 months after you asked the question.

[plunker]: https://plnkr.co/edit/w5kYI4?p=info
[zonejs-project]: https://github.com/angular/zone.js
[zonejs-project-issues]: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues
```

## Validation Error

[image: Failed validation message]

Comment: Markdown was tested in the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/294997#294997) to determine what was triggering the validation failure.

Comment: Can you try it with spaces before your link references?

Comment: @Cai : I've tried the links with spaces `[zonejs-project]: https://github.com/angular/zone.js`. 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 leading spaces. All seem to fail validation. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DavidPostill : It looks lie you were able to edit in the markdown change I wasn't able to make. Any idea what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @DavidPostill will only be pinged on the answer he edited btw :)